# "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'subs'" when trying to loop through factorials

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find partial sums of [(-1)^n*sqrt(pi)*x^(2n+1)]/[(2n+1)*(n!)] and plot them. I am doing so by iteratively finding the values of the expression between 0 and the number to which I want to find the sum, putting them in a list and summing the list. For some reason it gives me the error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'subs' and I think it has something to do with the factorial function from sympy.

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=symbols('n')
x=symbols('x')
a=((-1)**(n)*sqrt(pi)*x**(2*n+1))/((2*n+1)*factorial(n))

a0to5=[a.subs({n:i}) for i in range(6)]
s5=sum(a0to5)
a0to10=[a.subs({n:i}) for i in range(11)]
s10=sum(a0to10)
a0to15=[a.subs({n:i}) for i in range(16)]
s15=sum(a0to15)

t=symbols('t')
function=E**((-t)**2)
integral=(sqrt(pi))*integrate(function,t)
f=integral.subs(t,0)-integral.subs(t,x)

plot((s5,(x,-10,10)),(s10,(x,-10,10)),(s15,(x,-10,10)),(f,(x,-10,10)),ylim=[-2,2])
```

I did the exact same thing for an expression with no factorials and it worked.

Comment: Your actual code works perfectly fine for me. (Copy/Paste and Run). [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jvnB.png)

Comment: The code in the post doens't use numpy arrays, while your error message tells it encountered numpy. Note that numpy and sympy don't mix well, and preferably shouldn't be called in the same part of your code. If you do `from sympy import *`, it is highly recommended not to use anything like numpy or scipy in that part of your code.

Comment: What line?  Which variable is it that is a numpy array instead of sympy expression?